# Cannot install tensorflow js

Tags: tensorflow, npm, terminal, dependencies

I am trying to install tensorflow dependency but I am getting an error in the terminal console.

My package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "knn-tf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^0.1.17",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "shuffle-seed": "^1.1.6"
  }
}
```

```html
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
/Users/mateusz/WebstormProjects/ML_JS/MLKits/knn-tf/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/scripts/install.js:154
      throw new Error('node-gyp rebuild failed with: ' + err);
      ^

Error: node-gyp rebuild failed with: Error: Command failed: node-gyp rebuild
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.



gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mateusz/WebstormProjects/ML_JS/MLKits/knn-tf/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
gyp ERR! not ok 

    at /Users/mateusz/WebstormProjects/ML_JS/MLKits/knn-tf/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/scripts/install.js:154:13
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
npm WARN knn-tf@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN knn-tf@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.21 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.21 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mateusz/.npm/_logs/2020-06-05T21_16_30_200Z-debug.log
```

This occurs when I am running *npm i*

I have tried to remove the **node_modules** and install it from scratches but It has not helped.

Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some node modules are using node-gyp to compile their code.

in your case, you are using macos so you need to install compilation tools for macos.

you can do that by installing command line tools. this can be done easily by executing

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

or installing [xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) from the app store

once the command line tools are installed, re-run `npm install` (will advise you to delete `node_module` directory before)

Comment: I had it installed. However, removing the xcode-select and installing it again with the newest version has helped.